# Flash/Flashdevelop AS3 - Window is larger than what I set in Properties

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I'm making a game in FlashDevelop. I've set the Dimensions in Project -> Properties to 600 x 600.

Only, when I run it, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXX4U.png

Looks okay, right? Except it's 750 x 750, not 600 x 600.

I noticed this earlier but figured this was just a quirk with FlashDevelop and continued programming... up to now.

My game is nearly finished, you see, so I've uploaded it to FGL.com for peer review and whatnot. When I run it there, this is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzZ6b.png

Still a 750 x 750 window, but now my game isn't stretched to fill it so there's an ugly border on the side and the bottom.

I have no idea what could possibly be causing this, and I can't find any evidence of anyone else on the internet ever having this problem. The closest thing to an answer I found was to insert this line:

[SWF(width = "600", height = "600")]

But that didn't work.

I'm so frustrated. My first game is almost complete, but I've run into this dumb issue that completely ruins it and I have no idea what to do about it. I just know that it's either some stupidly obvious thing that I'm missing, or it's something horribly complicated that nobody has ever experienced before. That seems to be how it goes with me.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured out a workaround.

I added this to the title screen, which everything is a child of:

```css
if (stage.stageWidth >=stage.stageHeight) 
{
  this.scaleY=stage.stageHeight / 600;
  this.scaleX=stage.stageHeight / 600;
}
else 
{
  this.scaleY=stage.stageWidth / 600;
  this.scaleX=stage.stageWidth / 600;
}
```

It just scales the whole game to fit the window, whatever size it may be.